# Filtering (more than once) a Pointcloud

Tags: kinect, pcl, pcl-ros, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all, I've been trying to use the point cloud generated by a Kinect camera to fill an occupancy grid. To do so, I have used a passthrough filter (following the information provided [in this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/10520/how-to-get-the-point-clouds-in-a-region-of-kinect)), and the filter is working as expected using an adaptation of [this code](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/passthrough.php#passthrough).

The thing is, in that sample of code both the input and the output cloud are of the same data type (pointcloud::ptr), so if I wanted to filter the same cloud more than once (on two different axis, for instance), there shouldn't be a problem. But when I try to do it with the output I'm getting from the camera, the compiler says I need a const pointer for the input, and a pointcloud for the output of the filter.

Things I've tried:

- Using Pointcloud2Ptr as the data type (instead of just pointcloud2). The code compiles just fine, but the execution fails with an unhelpful error ("Assertion failed"). It appears to be a problem with how I've used the contructor, but since 2 out of 3 links for pointcloud2 404'd when I was looking for information, I'm not entirely sure what is the correct way to initialize the pointcloud pointers.
- Various combinations of referencing/dereferencing both the pointclouds and the pointers. None of them seemed to be correct.
- Converting the input cloud from pointcloud2 to pointcloud and using the same code linked above. This does in fact return the same error, assertion failed.

So, my question is: am I facing this problem correctly? Is there a way to use the same pointcloud as both the input and the output cloud of a passthrough filter?

I hope I didn't miss any important information.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29595/filtering-(more-than-once)-a-pointcloud./) by [JoaquinV](https://answers.ros.org/users/1697/joaquinv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2012-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, PCL filters are not meant to be used in-place; if that works, all that's happened is that you've gotten lucky.

And `.makeShared()` does, in fact, make a copy. In general, the way to use PCL is to do everything as a pointer explicitly; the correct construction is then

`pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>());`

which gets you a smart pointer for passing around (a `boost::shared_ptr`, behind the scenes).

I *strongly* recommend a typedef or three to make that less painful to type...

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4